# в чём разница между snapshot и backup у Digitalocean

Tags: linux

здравствуйте, в чём разница между snapshot и backup у digital ocean? там есть документация, но дословный английский перевод не очень понятный

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/digitalocean-backups-and-snapshots-explained

> The main difference between the two is that snapshots can be generated manually, while backups are run automatically weekly.

мой вольный перевод:

> главное отличие состоит в том, что snapshot может быть сгенерирован вручную, в то время как backup выполняется еженедельно автоматически.